# Javascript - Add images

Tags: javascript, image, addition

I have some images (image1, image2, image3 ..etc. ) and I will add those images to each cell seperately. I found a code to insert the images.

```
document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML = "<img src='image1.png'>";
```

Now, Can someone help me to put above code in a  loop in order to avoid to write same code for each image ?
I have tried below code but it does not work. Probably there is a problem with quotes. Or is there a better way to insert multiple images to each cells ?

```
for (x=0; x=10; x++) {
document.getElementById("'cell" + x + "'").innerHTML = "<img src=" + "' + x + ".png'>"; }
```

Comment: Element ids don't have the single quotes.

Comment: Youre missing the word image from your file name: `"<img src='image" + x + ".png'>"`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (x=0; x=10; x++) {
    document.getElementById("cell" + x).innerHTML = "<img src='image" + x + ".png' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (x=0; x=10; x++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'image' + x + '.png';
    document.getElementById('cell' + x).appendChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed creating elements from html strings can get really messy really quick.

Its often a a better idea to use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) to create the elements and then manipulate the properties of the element.

```
img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "image" + i + ".png"; // image1.png ... etc
```

Another very useful technique is using [document fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment) to create ad-hoc collections of elements before we actually attach them to the real document or elements.

```
frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
frag.appendChild(img);
targetNode.appendChild(fragment); // attach all the images in the fragment
```

This is [good for performance](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) since actually touching the DOM is slow - we don't want to do it over and over in a loop.

Lets take these two techniques and create a function which creates `img` elements

```
function createImages(n){
    var i, frag, img;
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "image" + i + ".png"; // image1.png ... etc
        frag.appendChild(img);
    }
    return frag;
}
```

We could use this function to attach images to each cell in table

```
var table = document.getElementById('test'),
    cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

(function(){
    var i, 
        len = cells.length,
        images = createImages(3);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cells[i].appendChild( images.cloneNode(true) );
    }
}());
```